# Do my metrics justify changing the MAXDOP settings?

Tags: sql-server, vmware

I recently took over a dual instance virtualized SQL Server with 8 x vCPUs and 8 x physical cores.  This is the only VM on the host.

`MAXDOP` is at the default setting.

The server has 100 high transaction vendor specific databases with some very nasty reporting queries.

`CXPacket` waits are at the top of the waits list with 63%.

Signal Waits are averaging 15.50%.

In PerfMon the Processor Queue Length rarely breaches 1.

Does this justify setting `MAXDOP` to 4 or 6?

Comment: The purpose of lowering parallelism would be to increase concurrency. If you are getting CPU queuing then concurrency wouldn't appear to be a problem. I see no reason to justify lowering Max DOP. I would want to get rid of multi-instances though.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about total waits. The funny thing about ranked lists is something has to always be the top item. I would look at waits of active queries and find queries that are experiencing high CXPacket waits and see if it can be tuned to run more optimally.

Comment: I agree with all of the above however that does not mean that `MAXDOP` cannot be an issue on either a virtual machine or a machine with hyper threading. Testing a lower `MAXDOP` could be one of many things you test while trying to optimize the overall query. I however doubt it will resolve your issue.

Comment: `MAXDOP` to reduce `CXPACKET` waits is like turning up the radio when your car starts making a loud grinding noise - the symptom goes away but not the root cause.

Comment: Love that analogy JNK. I made a similar analogy about CXPacket waits in a blog post called The Barking Dog analogy: http://www.sqlsoldier.com/wp/sqlserver/thebarkingdoganalogy

Answer (score 1):

I would investigate the CXPacket issues first - see what's causing those.  Can you identify a selection of queries that cause those wait types?  Can you then see what is causing the problem through the actual execution plan?  You're looking at `gather streams` steps, and looking for uneven loads coming in.  Try to identify the source of those - a likely suspect is out-of-date / not helpful index statistics.